# Mesh deformation after armature parenting

Tags: rigging, armature

When I tried to set parent with automatic weights my mesh was deformed.
What did I wrong?

[image: Not parented]
[image: parented]

Comment: I followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU  but with own model

Comment: I looked at this topic but it didn't help me https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8458/setting-parent-to-armature-with-automatic-weights-deforms-the-mesh

Comment: blend file here http://dropmefiles.com/KqoH5 or here https://files.fm/f/m2r66sbg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rig is not in its "rest pose". To set the current pose as the rest pose press Ctrl+A then apply as rest pose

Checkout [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49768/can-i-set-my-pose-position-like-the-new-rest-position) answer for more details:

Comment: When I try to do it warning is appearing http://prntscr.com/ft4gk2

Comment: @DmtriyIlchenko that's just saying that any animations made before setting this new rest pose will get messed up.